# Error when running Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

Can any one suggest me why the following error is occurring and how to resolve it??
Not only the below command, running any command related to Hive is returning the same..

```
hive> show databases;
FAILED: Error in metadata: MetaException(message:Got exception: org.apache.thrif
t.transport.TTransportException java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by pe
er: socket write error)
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTa
sk
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your *hive-site.xml*. It is possible your `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL`, the URL for the Hive metastore, isn't right.

Comment: My hive-site.xml has the following:

javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL is jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;database=hive;encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true;create=true


javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName is com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver


hive.metastore.warehouse.dir is /hive/warehouse


Please suggest me if any changes needed? Im using SQLServer.

Comment: I've actually never seen SQLServer used for the metastore. That doesn't mean necessarily it can't work, but I bet that is the source of your issue as it stands. Might want to research that. This [resource](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/igorpag/archive/2013/11/12/how-to-create-a-sql-server-linked-server-to-hdinsight-hive-using-microsoft-hive-odbc-driver.aspx) may help.